# The purpose of comparing with `+Infinity` explicitly in `ToLength`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The standard (ES2016) defines the `ToLength` operation as

1. Let `len` be ? `ToInteger(argument)`.
2. If `len ≤ +0`, return `+0`.
3. If `len` is `+∞`, return `2^53-1`.
4. Return `min(len, 2^53-1)`.

Why is the step 3 necessary here? Would not the `min(len, 2^53-1)` handle the case when `len is +Infinity`?

PS: In ES2015 it is slightly different but with the same "redundant" step.

**UPD**: see a link to the tc39 repository where I addressed the same concerns.

References:

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-tolength
- https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/721

Comment: could it be greater than 2^53-1 but smaller than infinity?

Comment: @dandavis `min(len, 2^53-1)` for that value would return `2^53-1`

Comment: pseudocode is pseudo, and as such covers all possibilities even if it seems like overkill ... implementation can combine 2 or more steps into one

Comment: @JaromandaX being "pseudo" does not mean it should contain redundant steps ;-) Compare with ES2015 - they removed a lot of redundancy from there.

Comment: hmm, true. the only benefit might be performance, but would the spec care?

Comment: @zerkms which language is the javascript engine written in? It may not be redundant at all in a language as yet unwritten

Comment: @JaromandaX how would it not be redundant? (irregardless of the language)

Comment: @zerkms - do you know the nuances of every single programming language in existence? Even those not written yet?

Comment: @JaromandaX - `min(len, 2^53-1)` is unambiguous regardless of the language. I would not want to use a language that thought that Infinity was less than 2^53-1.

Comment: @JaromandaX what kind of nuances are we talking about?

Comment: is it such a big deal that a specification includes a statement that seems redundant? Better too much information in the specification than too little

Comment: "is it such a big deal" --- it's not, but curiosity :-) If I know why it has it - I know more useless stuff (which is fun) :-)

Comment: @zerkms - the type of nuance that could cause step 3 to fail

Comment: @JaromandaX the standard requires the numbers to implement IEEE754 doubles, so a standard compliant implementation **MUST NOT** fail.

Comment: @zerkms - you're thinking from a javascript point of view - it's redundant in javascript - but the spec isn't about how to write **in** javascript, it's about how to create a compliant javascript interpreter/engine

Comment: @JaromandaX if that was true - the referred item must have had an explicit comparison with `-Infinity`

Comment: Seriously, this is a non issue as far as I can see. Implementers are free to write code that isn't redundant

Comment: I think this question should be directed at the authors of ECMA-262 (TC39 mailing list?) since only they know why they wrote what they wrote. The step seems like premature optimisation, the spec says: "*The algorithms are not intended to imply the use of any specific implementation technique. In practice, there may be more efficient algorithms available to implement a given feature.*"

Comment: The ES2017 spec removes the redundant step https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tolength

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was found - it was redundant and improved in the following PR: https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/738

Answer (score 1):

Given that Math.min returns 2^32-1 when given the option of that or Infinity, I suspect it's the spec writers being overzealous.

```
> Math.min(Infinity, Math.pow(2, 53)-1)
9007199254740991
```

In addition, "min" doesn't really have a meaning when Infinities are involved. While Infinity can have a positive or negative value, +Infinity is not always greater than all other values. Infinity can sometimes mean "undefined number" and can sometimes be figured out using Limits. Just don't ask me for an example here.

Answer (score 1):

`ToLength` will not return an `Infinity` value even though It's
considerd as a number.

```
If len is Infinity
  return max_safe_integer
else
  return min(len, max_safe_integer)
```

> Why is the step 3 necessary here?

If `len` is `Infinity`, This step will do much less operation for a function to return a `Number`. Since `min` is implemented to do more operation than just checking by using [abstract relational comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison).

Comment: "This step will do much less operation for a function" --- so it's an implementation optimisation directly in the standard? How is it helpful if it's not enforcible then? (the V8 does not implement it like that)

Comment: I have no idea about how the engines are supposed to operate this. But seeing they implement it that way, I say yes, it's to optimize the operation. Tried to imagine the operation without the step 3 above in asm and I somehow think its better this way.

Comment: That's ugly and makes very little sense to me, but at least I can accept it, thanks :-)

Comment: If this concerns you, though I have no idea how the engines operate it. But, they are supposed to implement ES as specified in Ecma-262 specs (especially v8).

Comment: They are supposed to keep semantics, not follow it exactly. The presence of the step 3 is not enforcible or distinguishable (and as expected - there is no such step in for example v8). Anyway, I asked a question to the TC39 themselves.

Comment: use emoticons (comment reactions) not `+1`s :-)

Comment: I just wanted to subscribe, since I am also curious why.. :)

Comment: There is a "subscribe" button on the right (now it presumably is "unsubscribe" for you)